# Debian kvm switch reset screen resolution

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, resolution

I'm using debian Jessie with mate 1.8.1, I have 2 computers connected on a single screen with a kvm switch in a resolution of 1920*1200.

When one of the computer is left idle for a long period of time, the screen resolution reset to something that would look like 1920*1080.

When the resolution is reseted, I just have to go to System -> preference -> monitor and without having to change any setting, everything is back to normal.

Both my computer are on debian Jessie / mate 1.8.1, but only the second one is doing this.

My second computer have a amd video card :

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos
[Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]
```

and before using a kvm switch, the computer was plugged on a `1920*1080` monitor.

I change the setting to never put the display on sleep, but the problem persist.
I also tried 2 different kvm switch, and both are supposed to be able to get up to 1920*1200 without any issue.

I also tried to modify the `xorg.conf` file to manually put the resolution, but once again, nothing work.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?